# Populate a javascript array randomly with pre-defined values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I can't seem to figure this out. I see lots of answers about filling an array with number sequentially, but not what I'm looking for.

I need to populate an array of pre-defined length, the shortest being 4, that will be populated randomly with wither "apple" or "Orange.  So basically turn:

```
var fruit= [];
```

to

```
var fruit= [apple, orange, orange, apple];
```

where the elements are put in randomly from the list of two options.

Comment: What have you tried? please show some code

Comment: Loop, pick a random number from 0-len of possible value, append to result array.

Comment: To randomly generate 0 or 1 you may use: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)`. Associate 0 to `apple` and 1 to `orange`. I'll leave you to finish the exercise...

Comment: THANK YOU.  The math.random piece is what I was missing. I have used that previously but it totally slipped my mind.  Thanks Matteo for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate an array and map random elements.

```js
function getRandomFruits(n) {
    return Array.from({ length: n }, _ => ['apple', 'orange'][Math.round(Math.random())]);
}

console.log(getRandomFruits(4));
console.log(getRandomFruits(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let fruit = []; 
let possible = ["Orange", "Apple"]; 
let preDefinedLength = 4; 
for(let i = 0; i < preDefinedLength; i++){ 
   let choice = Math.floor((Math.random() * possible.length)); 
   fruit.push(possible[choice]);
}
```